# Python Error~ List index out of range

Tags: python

```
def getSublists(L,n):
    List=L
    sublists=[]
    for i in range(len(L)-(n-1)):
        ii=0
        sub=[]
        while ii<= n:
            a=List[ii+i]
            sub.append(a)
            ii+=1
        sublists.append(sub)

    return sublists
```

I am trying to get all of the possible sublists of a list L and of sublist size n. I am getting an `IndexError: list index out of range` when I try to run my program. I've messed around with it to no avail and have read other relevant posts. Can someone help me out?

Comment: So for the input list `[1,2,3,4,5]` and n=3 you want `[1,2,3]`, `[2,3,4]`, and `[3,4,5]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your while condition should be modified:

```
def getSublists(L,n):
    List=L
    sublists=[]
    for i in range(len(L)-(n-1)):
        print ['i: ', i]
        ii=0
        sub=[]
        while ii<= n-1:
            print ['ii: ', ii]
            a=List[ii+i]
            sub.append(a)
            ii+=1
        sublists.append(sub)

    return sublists
```

for a list of 10, you can now query all sub lists of 5

```
a=range(10)
b=getSublists(a,5)

out:
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Sometimes you just need another set of eyes to see the problem.

Comment: no problem. I'll appreciate if you accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to only append to the sublists array if the sublist is of length n, then break once it is. Otherwise, `ii+i` could increase beyond `len(L) - 1`, leading to the index error.

```
    if len(sub) == n:
        sublists.append(sub)
        break
```

Here's a working solution (assuming what you want is what L3viathan asked in comments).

```
def getSublists(L,n):
    List=L
    sublists=[]
    for i in range(len(L)-(n-1)):
        ii=0
        sub=[]
        while ii<= n:
            a=List[ii+i]
            sub.append(a)
            ii+=1
            if len(sub) == n:
                sublists.append(sub)
                break

    return sublists
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be fixed changing the while statement to **while ii < n**, in case you're trying to obtain this result:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4] n = 2
nl = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

But I think this is not what you want. Now, if you're lazy as me, you can use itertools.combinations to get all possible combinations.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Demonstration:

```
import itertools
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
nl = itertools.combinations(l, 2)
nl = list(nl)
print nl
```

Result = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]